# How to resolve EF7 current database context in ASP NET 5 out of the controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to get one context per request in ASP NET 5/EF 7 app for use it in some methods (not in controller).

Unfortunately I did not find the answer in the documentation 
[ASP.NET vNext template](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Configuring-a-DbContext#aspnet-vnext-template) and examples [aspnet/MusicStore](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore)

Comment: Aren't you going to call these `some methods` from your Controllers? You can get context per request and pass it to `some methods`.

Comment: it's not comfortable, there may be multiple calls. In MVC5 apps i used UnityDependencyResolver with PerRequestLifetimeManager. I am trying to do something similar here

Comment: It will do exactly what you need - create DbContext per request, inject it into your controller, from there within single request you can pass it to multiple `some methods` as much as you want. Check out [this blog post](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/resolve-dbcontext-as-interface-in-aspnet5-ioc-container) for more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use some methods for achieving this purpose.

Using `.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();` method for registering `ApplicationDbContext` in Dependency Injection system (in `ConfigureServices()` method), leads to the fact that it  registered as Scoped dependence(or in another words "per request"). Thereby you only need get it from Dependency Injection system.

1. Add your dbContext as parameter of constructor method your class (in which you will use dbContext). Then you have to get this class using Dependency Injection system, e.g added it as parameter of controller's constructor.

   ```
   public class HabitsController : Controller
   {
       public HabitsController(HabitService habitService)
       {

       }
   }

   public class HabitService
   {
       private GetHabitsContext _dbContext;

       public HabitService(GetHabitsContext dbContext)
       {
           _dbContext = dbContext;
       }
   }
   ```
2. But if you don't want to use constructor injection for getting context, you can get necessary dependenses using `GetService()` method (but you need in ServiceProvider instance for that, in example below, i'am getting it through constructor injection too).

   ```
   using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection; // for beta 6 and below
   using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; // for beta 7 and above
   public class HabitService
   {
       private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

       public HabitService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
       {
           _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
       }

       public GetHabit()
       {
            var dbcontext = _serviceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
       }
   }
   ```
3. In first method, we can get `HabitService` through `GetService()` method too (not through the constructor injection).

   ```
   using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection; // for beta 6 and below
   using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; // for beta 7 and above

   public class HabitsController : Controller
   {
       public HabitsController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
       {
          var habitService= serviceProvider.GetService<HabitService>();
       }
   }

   public class HabitService
   {
       private GetHabitsContext _dbContext;

       public HabitService(GetHabitsContext dbContext)
       {
           _dbContext = dbContext;
       }
   }
   ```

Thanks Tseng for remark:

> I should be noted, that it's a pretty bad practice to inject the container into your objects. The container should only be referenced from the composition root and certain type of factories (which are implemented on application level, and not in the domain/business layer)

---

> dbContext in HabitsController and _dbContext in HabitService are different contexts!

I checked, this is the same context.

Comment: I should be noted, that it's a pretty bad practice to inject the container into your objects. The container should only be referenced from the composition root and certain type of factories (which are implemented on application level, and not in the domain/business layer)

Comment: Say no to `_` use `this.dbContext = dbContext`

Comment: @SerjSagan why say no to _? I reckon say no to this. and base.